# Previous layout get clicked from overlaped layout in Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, android-relativelayout

I have two reletive layout. First has spinner and recyclerview and second has a imageview. Second layout overlap first layout on button click. But when I click on second layout, first layout spinner and recylerview get clicked and it shows on second layout.

Comment: can you post the code of your activity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"`

to your image view layout. It will not propagate your clicks to your first layout.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on ImageView that click event is propagated to view under it automatically. If you block click event after using in ImageView then it will not trigger any click events on ImageView.

e.g.

```
class TouchBlockingImageView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ImageView(context, attrs) {

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Use your logic to handle click event
        return true
    }

}
```

If we return `true` in `onTouchEvent` then android will not pass that touch event to next layer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You Should set Visibility as Gone. 
So it Will not get any click

Answer :- 
(Your layout / any view ).setVisibility("VIEW.GONE");